# Python: ensure class attributes are not shared between common inheritance trees

Tags: python, inheritance

I have the feeling I've seen this somewhere, but am no longer sure whether that's a re-constructed memory or if it really exists. In any case I cannot find a reference to this situation:

```
class A:
    a = 1

class B(A):  # should have it's own class attribute 'a'
    pass

class C(A):  # should have it's own class attribute 'a' and newly defined 'c'
    c = 3
```

In the above example, `A.a is B.a is C.a`. But, I actually wanted them to be separate while keeping this structure. There is a good reason for this and I don't want to discuss instance variables. The reason for that is that in my application all these classes are used as 'namespaces'. To solve the 'issue', I replace `A` inherited parts by a copy of itself as (pseudo code):

```
class A:
    a = 1

class B(A):  # B.a resolves to A.a
    pass

class C(A):  # C.a resolves to A.a
    c = 3

copy_func(B.A, A)  # investigates public attrs of A and B and create copies, now B.a is not A.a
copy_func(C.A, A)  # investigates public attrs of A and B and create copies, now C.a is not A.a
```

Comment: There is no way for two ``1``s or ``3``s to not be identical. Do you use mutable values in your actual usecase?

Comment: *Values* are not inherited, only names. It's more accurate to say that `C.a` *resolves* to `A.a` than that `C` has an attribute named `a`.

Comment: Do you have an actual question, like how to define `copy_func`?

Comment: I do have a working `copy_func`. My question is whether there is some trick I am missing that would simplify the whole thing directly at the class inheritance implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `__init_subclass__` to automatically copy superclass-attributes when a childclass is defined.

```py
import copy

class A:
    a = []

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        for base in cls.mro():
            for attr in base.__dict__:
                if attr not in cls.__dict__ and not attr.startswith("_"):
                    setattr(cls, attr, copy.copy(getattr(cls, attr)))
```

This will copy everything from the superclass namespace that does not start with `_`. In practice, one might want to apply more restrictive rules.

The `__init_subclass__` is automatically run when a subclass is defined. This means subclasses gain the copied attributes without having to run code explicitly.

```py
class B(A):
    pass

class C(A):
    c = 3

assert B.a is not A.a
assert C.a is not A.a
```

Comment: I am accepting this answer, because it is actually a good suggestion. Due to the way my package is built (especially its size), it would actually become almost unreadable to use this implementation and I'll keep the `copy_func` version... but it is still a good answer.